# How to prevent the file to overwrite itself?

Tags: java, java-io

i've edited the code, can you please tell me how i can write each line at the end of the file? Here it's been written on the same line. Can you help please?

```
private void okMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                
    String pass = name.getText();
    if (pass.equals("")){
        error.setText("Name of Entity should not be left blank");
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Name of Entity should not be left blank");
    }
    else{
        try{

            Formatter outfile = new Formatter(new FileOutputStream("Convert.sql", true));
            outfile.format("Create Database IF NOT EXISTS " + pass + ";");
            outfile.close();

        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
            System.out.println("Not found");

        }
        this.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: The word you're looking for is 'overwrite', and SQL has nothing to do with it. Neither does Swing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass to the constructor of `Formatter` a `FileOutputStream` created in append mode:

```
Formatter outfile = new Formatter(new FileOutputStream("Convert.sql", true));
outfile.format("Create Database IF NOT EXISTS " + pass + ";\n");  // \n to add new line
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter(java.io.OutputStream).

Comment: Thanks it worked @manouti. But How can i add each statement at the end of the file and not on the same line?

Comment: @LanaM Just add a newline (`\n`) character when writing: `outfile.format("Create Database IF NOT EXISTS " + pass + ";\n");`